# Building images using docker-compose and containerd?

Tags: docker-compose, containerd

I have a build working fine with docker-compose; however, I was requested to have it build through a pipeline which only has containerd installed, it isn't configured to listen on any port but uses the socket path

Is it even possible to use docker-compose without dockerd, just containerd?